# what is wrong with this piece of code?i am getting "null pointer exception".code is about drawing route on map

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {

    String origin;
    String destination=String.valueOf(l.longitude)+","+String.valueOf(l.latitude);
    origin=String.valueOf(longitude)+","+String.valueOf(latitude);
   // String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+ output + "?" + params;
    String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+origin+"&destination="+destination+"&sensor=false";
    return url;
}
```

I am getting `NullPointerException`. I know what it is but not able to identify what is causing it. Assuming everything outside this method is correct, what is wrong syntactically?

This is my entire code:

```
package autogenie.maptrial;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {
    private double latitude, longitude;
    public GoogleMap googleMap,googleMap1;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Button addressButton;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment fragment;
    LatLng l;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        addressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addressButton);
        fragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
        ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
        downloadTask.execute(url);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }


        addressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_place_name);
                String address = editText.getText().toString();

                GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new GeocodingLocation();
                locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());

               l= getLocationFromAddress(getApplicationContext(), address);
                MarkerOptions a=new MarkerOptions().position(l);

                Marker m=googleMap.addMarker(a);
                m.setPosition(l);




            }



        });



        fragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) { // Handle the selected Place
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) { // Handle the error
            }


        });



    }


    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context,String strAddress) {

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng p1 = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 1);
            if (address == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return p1;
    }


    private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            String locationAddress;
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                    locationAddress = bundle.getString("address");
                    break;
                default:
                    locationAddress = null;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),locationAddress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            latitude = 28.608426;
            longitude = 77.225168;
        } else {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        String s = "longitude:" + longitude + "latitude:" + latitude;
        Log.i("Current location", " latlong value" + s);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title("Hello world"));


        /*CameraUpdate center =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,
                        -longitude));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

        googleMap.moveCamera(center);
        googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);*/

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

    }

   //dfg

    private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {




       // String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+ output + "?" + params;
        String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+l+"&destination="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=false";
        return url;
    }



    private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String data = "";
            try {
                HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
                data = http.readUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }


        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

        // traversing through routes
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
            polyLineOptions.width(2);
            polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }


        googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    }

}




class GeocodingLocation {

    private static final String TAG = "GeocodingLocation";
    public  String result1,result2;

    public  void getAddressFromLocation(final String locationAddress,
                                              final Context context, final Handler handler) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                String result = null;
                try {
                    List
                            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                        sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
                        result = sb.toString();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e);
                } finally {
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.setTarget(handler);
                    if (result != null) {
                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                "\n\nLatitude and Longitude :\n" + result;
                        bundle.putString("address", result);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    } else {
                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                "\n Unable to get Latitude and Longitude for this address location.";
                        bundle.putString("address", result);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    }
                    message.sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }


}
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.aw.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:137)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
at autogenie.maptrial.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:315)
at autogenie.maptrial.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:267)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-21 12:24:35.291 3683-3683/autogenie.maptrial I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3683 SIG: 9
```

Comment: l is not initialized

Comment: can you post at which line you getting exception? and may be your l location may be null.

Comment: post your whole code with logcat

Comment: should'nt 'origin' variable be of type latlng?

Answer (score 1):

one of your variables(l, latitude, longitude) is null since the only place that might cause the exception is the valueOf calls.

Comment: should'nt 'origin' variable be of type latlng?

Comment: you are assigning string to origin ... even if you assign null this wont cause the exception. The exception cause is
String.valueOf(null);

Comment: could you put 
 PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    options.add(new LatLng(25.2048,55.2708));
    googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions());


as the last line of your onPostExecute() 
and comment googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);